# Can Spark guarantee cpu for per task?

Tags: apache-spark

If I set cpu.task=1, how can Spark guarantee the task exclusively using the cpu?  As I recall, cpu schedule is done by kernel and is transparent for user.

Answer (score 0):

It is not belong to Spark stuff, **it should belong to the underlying resource manager, such as Hadoop Yarn or Mesos**.

Ref:

1. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html